# How Apostrophe is stored in database using php form text area?

Tags: php, mysql, post, textarea, apostrophe

I have a code file with name of "form.php". In this I create a web form and using text area tag in it. I have a problem. When I write something in text area and use Apostrophe in my text then data can not store in database. But when I write text without Apostrophe data stored in database. How can I fix my problem?

My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("aaaaa", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$txtTitle = $_POST['txtTitle'];
$txtReferance = $_POST['txtReferance'];
$txtToName = $_POST['txtToName'];
$chkConfidential = $_POST['chkConfidential'];
$txtToDesignation = $_POST['txtToDesignation'];
$txtDate = $_POST['txtDate'];
$cmbSolutation = $_POST['cmbSolutation'];
$txtToEntity = $_POST['txtToEntity'];
$txtToAdd1 = $_POST['txtToAdd1'];
$txtThankYou = $_POST['txtThankYou'];
$txtToAdd2 = $_POST['txtToAdd2'];
$cmbYoursTruely = $_POST['cmbYoursTruely'];
$txtToAdd3 = $_POST['txtToAdd3'];
$txtSignatureName = $_POST['txtSignatureName'];
$txtToCity = $_POST['txtToCity'];
$cmbSDesignation = $_POST['cmbSDesignation'];
$txtHeading1 = $_POST['txtHeading1'];
$txtEnch1 = $_POST['txtEnch1'];
$txtHeading2 = $_POST['txtHeading2'];
$txtEnch2 = $_POST['txtEnch2'];
$txtHeading3 = $_POST['txtHeading3'];
$txtEnch3 = $_POST['txtEnch3'];
$txtRational = $_POST['txtRational'];


//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(file_name, ref_no, to_name, confidential, designation, date, solutation, entity, add_1, thank_you, add_2, yours_truly, add_3, sign_name, city, s_designation, heading_line_1, encl_line_1, heading_line_2, encl_line_2, heading_line_3, encl_line_3, text) 

values 

    ('$txtTitle', '$txtReferance', '$txtToName', '$chkConfidential', '$txtToDesignation', '$txtDate', '$cmbSolutation', '$txtToEntity', '$txtToAdd1', '$txtThankYou', '$txtToAdd2', '$cmbYoursTruely', '$txtToAdd3', '$txtSignatureName', '$txtToCity', '$cmbSDesignation', '$txtHeading1', '$txtEnch1', '$txtHeading2', '$txtEnch2', '$txtHeading3', '$txtEnch3', '$txtRational')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}

//mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
?>
```

Comment: You should *not* be building a query with concatenation like this.  You should be using prepared statements.  The answer provided below "works" but does not fully protect against SQL injection in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Use it over every field to escape such characters.

```
$txtTitle = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['txtTitle'] );
// same for all other columns
```

PS: Use  [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)  , mysql is deprecated and slow too.

Comment: Hi Sunny, Please "accept" the answer, if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this before inserting the value to your database:

```
    $text = mysql_escape_string($_POST['text']);
```